# CodeIgniter CI_Exceptions::show_exception error after updating to PHP 7

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, php-7

I was using CodeIgniter 3.0.0 with PHP 5.6.

Yesterday I updated to PHP 7 and started getting following error:-

```
Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to CI_Exceptions::show_exception() must be
 an instance of Exception, instance of Error given, called in /my/file/path/app/system/core/Common.php on line 658 and defined in /my/file/path/hgx_portal/app/system/core/Exceptions.php:190
Stack trace:
#0 /my/file/path/hgx_portal/app/system/core/Common.php(658): CI_Exceptions->show_exception(Object
(Error))
#1 [internal function]: _exception_handler(Object(Error))
#2 {main}
  thrown in /my/file/path/hgx_portal/app/system/core/Exceptions.phpon line 190
```

Comment: Upgrade to Codeigniter 3.06 . If you are still having errors, please post on the codeigniter.com forum.

Comment: Actually I can not upgrae to CI 3.06. I think  I will have to roll back to PHP 5.6

Comment: CI 3.0 is over a year old so would encourage you to upgrade when you are able to.

Comment: OK, Thanks for suggestion. I would do so

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a know issue in CodeIgniter 3.0.0, see the github issue [here](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/4137) and [changelog](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/user_guide_src/source/changelog.rst#id308) below:

> Fixed a bug (#4137) - :doc:`Error Handling <general/errors>` breaks for the new Error exceptions under PHP 7.

It's because set_exception_handler() [changed behavior](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/user_guide_src/source/changelog.rst#id308) in PHP 7.

> Code that implements an exception handler registered with
>   set_exception_handler() using a type declaration of Exception will
>   cause a fatal error when an Error object is thrown.
>
> If the handler needs to work on both PHP 5 and 7, you should remove
>   the type declaration from the handler, while code that is being
>   migrated to work on PHP 7 exclusively can simply replace the Exception
>   type declaration with Throwable instead.
>
> ```
> <?php
> // PHP 5 era code that will break.
> function handler(Exception $e) { ... }
> set_exception_handler('handler');
>
> // PHP 5 and 7 compatible.
> function handler($e) { ... }
>
> // PHP 7 only.
> function handler(Throwable $e) { ... }
> ?>
> ```

Upgrading to anything beyond 3.0.2 will fix your issue.

Comment: Why are you linking to an issue that has been closed?

Comment: Sorry, I was supposed to also point out that the issue was only fixed in 3.0.2 where as the question above clearly stated they were running 3.0.0.

Comment: And the small detail that CI 3.00 was released months before the very first PHP 7 alpha.

Answer (score 12):

This error is caused by PHP 7 (which throws `Error` instead `Exception` in `set_exception_handler` function.

If you cannot do an upgrade the CodeIgniter system folder, you can just change the file `system/core/Exceptions.php` at line `190`:

```
public function show_exception(Exception $exception)
```

To

```
public function show_exception($exception)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just go to /system/core/Exceptions.php
open the file, and then 'save'

It works for me

I use macOS Monterey, PHP 8.1.2