# Where are PHP 7.2 Error Messages at? Upgrading PHP 5.6 to 7.2 and now error message isn't useful at all

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter 3.0, and upgrading from 5.6 to 7.2, but now the error messages are not useful at all, and I am wondering how to see see better error messages.

Here is an example of 7.2  [PHP 7.2 Unhelpful Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MfU8.png)
This isn't useful because it is just saying the error is somewhere in the CodeIgnitor exceptions controller, but this isn't the source of the actual bug.

Now to really find the error, I switch the version back to PHP 5.6 to see this error message: [PHP 5.6 Useful Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSLNG.png) This shows exactly which part of the code where there is an issue

Is there a new place I need to look for errors to get the same type of error message for PHP 7.2 that can lead me to the bug?

Comment: PHP 7 changes how most errors are reported. Please check the manual for more info https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36985153/2874291 Check it this helps